# Error logger using pandas, and datetime. Having issues formatting for pandas

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, datetime

I am writing a code that collects errors and logs them. I have a timer, and a text entry box that allows user input, and a button. Basically my idea is a user could type in an error press the "log error" button and have that stored in a pandas data frame. The format I am getting from my datetime is a little strange, it lists datetime.datetime before every entry, and the way it's split up in my list is a little weird. It has all the information. It separates every space with a comma though.  Wondering if anyone knows how to format this so it's nice and pretty for my data frame. I was hoping to get two columns. One for errors and one for the date and time the error was logged. I tried a few things with the DataFrame.columns command but  nothing seemed to work. Currently when printing my data frame it doesn't seem to have the Errors anywhere, and the time logged seems to be incorrect. I guess I could use a little help formatting and setting up my data frame.

```
import tkinter as tk #tkinter is used for the gui window and button etc.
import datetime # datetime is used for our timers
import pandas as pd #pandas will be used for storing our data.

window = tk.Tk()  #naming our window: window
window.title("DPT10")  #here I set the title of the window to DPT10
window.geometry("250x80")  #here we set the size of the window

label1 = tk.Label(text=currenttime, padx=10, pady=5) #creating the size and placement for our timer
label1.place(x=10, y=5, width=200, height=20)

label2 = tk.Label(text="Error:", padx=10, pady=5) #creating the size and placement for text entry box
label2.place(x=7, y=20, width= 30, height=20)
entry1 = tk.Entry(window,)
entry1.place(x=40, y=20, width=200, height=20)

button = tk.Button(window, text="Log Error", command=log)  #creating a button that runs the log program
button.place(x=70, y=45, width=70, height=20)


global time
global startzeit   
def timer():   #this program allows me to have a timer running with the date and time.
    global currenttime
    currenttime = datetime.datetime.today()
    window.after(1000, timer)  #this line sets the timer to change after 1000 milliseconds

def log():  #this program lets me store the time, and store the error logged by the user.
    global startzeit
    startzeit = datetime.datetime.today()  #seperate timer so that our log doesn't pick up every one second change.
    time = [(startzeit)]
    print (time)  #left this here to check if the time was logged every button press
    label1.config(text="Error has been logged") #once button is pressed this message shows briefly
    Error = [entry1.get()]  
    print (Error) #left this to check if the errors were logged every time button is pressed


def update_label(label1):   #This program allows the first label to update every second
    new_text = currenttime
    label1.configure(text=new_text)
    label1.after(1000, update_label, label1)
update_label(label1)
timer() #calling our timer once more to "run"

window.mainloop()
df = pd.DataFrame({'Errors': time})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
import tkinter as tk  # tkinter is used for the gui window and button etc.
import datetime  # datetime is used for our timers
import pandas as pd  # pandas will be used for storing our data.

window = tk.Tk()  # naming our window: window
window.title("DPT10")  # here I set the title of the window to DPT10
window.geometry("250x80")  # here we set the size of the window

time = []
stat = []
startzeit = []
currenttime = []


def log():  # this program lets me store the time, and store the error logged by the user.
    global startzeit
    global time
    global stat
    startzeit = datetime.datetime.today()  # seperate timer so that our log doesn't pick up every one second change.
    time.append(startzeit)
    label1.config(text="Error has been logged")  # once button is pressed this message shows briefly
    Error = [entry1.get()]
    stat.append(Error)
    print(Error)  # left this to check if the errors were logged every time button is pressed


label1 = tk.Label(text='currenttime', padx=10, pady=5)  # creating the size and placement for our timer
label1.place(x=10, y=5, width=200, height=20)

label2 = tk.Label(text="Error:", padx=10, pady=5)  # creating the size and placement for text entry box
label2.place(x=7, y=20, width=30, height=20)
entry1 = tk.Entry(window, )
entry1.place(x=40, y=20, width=200, height=20)

button = tk.Button(window, text="Log Error", command=log)  # creating a button that runs the log program
button.place(x=70, y=45, width=70, height=20)


def timer():  # this program allows me to have a timer running with the date and time.
    global currenttime
    currenttime = datetime.datetime.today()
    window.after(1000, timer)  # this line sets the timer to change after 1000 milliseconds


def update_label(label1):  # This program allows the first label to update every second
    new_text = currenttime
    label1.configure(text=new_text)
    label1.after(1000, update_label, label1)


update_label(label1)
timer()  # calling our timer once more to "run"

window.mainloop()
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(time, stat)),
                  columns=['time', 'errors'])
print(df)


##result
                        time     stat
0 2023-02-21 22:45:23.592409    [ttt]
1 2023-02-21 22:45:26.983698    [rrr]
2 2023-02-21 22:45:29.799383  [cfycy]
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! This is a really great start for what I want.

Comment: Very good, Please rate me.